# Pandas and JSON ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to make a simple application that will take lyrics from a song and save them, I'm using [lyricsgenius](https://github.com/johnwmillr/LyricsGenius) to create a JSON file with the lyrics of the songs I'm requesting, however, I can't figure out how to parse the data from the JSON file. I've tried following [this](https://medium.com/@RareLoot/how-to-download-an-artists-lyrics-from-genius-com-using-python-984d298951c6) tutorial but I am getting an error when I start working with Pandas.

Code to create the JSON File

```
import lyricsgenius as genius
import os

os.getcwd()

geniusCreds = "qlDFcHWqCRpSfq0pVTctt1ZhDc4wHF6lpP5WGODh4iVQB7yTPn7Hw6SjWAFiCdxa"
artist_name = "Steely Dan"

api = genius.Genius(geniusCreds)
artist = api.search_artist(artist_name, max_songs=3)

artist.save_lyrics()
```

Code to read the Data from the JSON File

```
import pandas as pd
import os


Artist = pd.read_json("Lyrics_SteelyDan.json")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Artist['songs'])

df.head
```

Whenever I run the code above I get the error, any help on how to fix the error or a better way to parse the data would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
 "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Steely Dan/Data.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Steely Dan/Data.py", line 5, in <module>
    Artist = pd.read_json("Lyrics_SteelyDan.json")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 592, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 717, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 739, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 849, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1093, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 411, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 257, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 77, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 368, in extract_index
    raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Comment: please paste the full traceback.

Comment: Can you also post the json?

Comment: If you have  a github can you post it there and link to it or provide a sample / portion of the json file.

Comment: Sorry, that repo (JSON-Snip) is returning a 404

Comment: Same 404; is it a public repo?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have different lengths if rows so your original code will fail.

Try this:

```
import json

with open('Lyrics_SteelyDan.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['songs'])
    df['lyrics']
```

Read also this: https://hackersandslackers.com/json-into-pandas-dataframes/

Comment: change `df = json_normalize(data)` to `df = pd.DataFrame(data['songs'])` then call the lyrics columns `df['lyrics']`

Comment: json_normalize() is deprecated...

Comment: Also they are spelling it with an S instead of a Z.